# Is there any memory leak in the following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, md5

If I calculate the MD5 value of a file about larger than 200Mb,the app will speed lots of memory and crash.Is there any memory leak in the following code?
Is there a better way to calculate the MD5 value of huge video file?

```
+ (NSString *) md5ForFileContent:(NSString *)path
{

    NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    if (handle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    CC_MD5_CTX md5;
    CC_MD5_Init (&md5);

    BOOL done = NO;

    while (!done) {

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData: [handle readDataOfLength:1024]];
        CC_MD5_Update (&md5, [fileData bytes], [fileData length]);

        if ([fileData length] == 0) {
                done = YES;
        }

        [fileData release];
        [pool release];

    }

    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5_Final (digest, &md5);

    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
               digest[0],  digest[1], 
               digest[2],  digest[3],
               digest[4],  digest[5],
               digest[6],  digest[7],
               digest[8],  digest[9],
               digest[10], digest[11],
               digest[12], digest[13],
               digest[14], digest[15]];
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Did you ask Instruments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a potential solution [here](http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/).  It uses the CFReadStream API.

Good luck

Tim

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use this method in a new thread,you must write the following code at the head of the method.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

And put this code at the end of the method

```
[pool release];
```